# Smart JScrollPane follows output text

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a smart JScrollPane but unlike every other solution out there I would like to know if the view port can follow (scrolling up with) the viewed component (JTextArea) if the scroll pane is not at the bottom AND if the text buffer is full.  Fully functional code snippet included.  Thanks.

```
public class ScrollingJTextAreaExample extends JFrame {
    // Worker thread to help periodically append example messages to JTextArea
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    // Merely informative counter, will be displayed with the example messages
    int messageCounter = 0;
    // GUI components
    JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    MyJTextArea jTextArea;

    public ScrollingJTextAreaExample() {
        initComponents(); // Boiler plate GUI construction and layout

        // Configure JTextArea to not update the cursor position after
        // inserting or appending text to the JTextArea. This disables the
        // JTextArea's usual behavior of scrolling automatically whenever
        // inserting or appending text into the JTextArea: we want scrolling
        // to only occur at our discretion, not blindly. NOTE that this
        // breaks normal typing into the JTextArea. This approach assumes
        // that all updates to the ScrollingJTextArea are programmatic.
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) jTextArea.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);

        // Schedule a task to periodically append example messages to jTextArea
        timer.schedule(new TextGeneratorTask(), 250, 250);

        // This DocumentListener takes care of re-scrolling when appropriate
        Document document = jTextArea.getDocument();
        document.addDocumentListener(new ScrollingDocumentListener());
    }

    // Boring, vanilla GUI construction and layout code
    private void initComponents() {
        jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea = new MyJTextArea();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(jTextArea);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(320, 240);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    // ScrollingDocumentListener takes care of re-scrolling when appropriate
    class ScrollingDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            maybeScrollToBottom();
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            maybeScrollToBottom();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            maybeScrollToBottom();
        }

        private void maybeScrollToBottom() {
            JScrollBar scrollBar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            boolean scrollBarAtBottom = isScrollBarFullyExtended(scrollBar);
            boolean scrollLock = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                    .getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK);
            if (scrollBarAtBottom && !scrollLock) {
                // Push the call to "scrollToBottom" back TWO PLACES on the
                // AWT-EDT queue so that it runs *after* Swing has had an
                // opportunity to "react" to the appending of new text:
                // this ensures that we "scrollToBottom" only after a new
                // bottom has been recalculated during the natural
                // revalidation of the GUI that occurs after having
                // appending new text to the JTextArea.
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                scrollToBottom(jTextArea);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    class TextGeneratorTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String message = (++messageCounter)
                            + " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. \n";
                    jTextArea.appendText(message);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static boolean isScrollBarFullyExtended(JScrollBar vScrollBar) {
        BoundedRangeModel model = vScrollBar.getModel();
        return (model.getExtent() + model.getValue()) == model.getMaximum();
    }

    public static void scrollToBottom(JComponent component) {
        Rectangle visibleRect = component.getVisibleRect();
        visibleRect.y = component.getHeight() - visibleRect.height;
        component.scrollRectToVisible(visibleRect);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ScrollingJTextAreaExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public class MyJTextArea extends JTextArea {
        DefaultCaret caret;
        static final int BUFFERSIZE = 100;

        public MyJTextArea() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());      
            setBackground(Color.black);
            setForeground(Color.white);
            setCaretColor(getForeground());
            setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            setLineWrap(false);            
            setEditable(false);
        }

        public void appendText(String text) {
            // When the line count in the text window > size of the buffer, 
            // replace the first line in buffer to give way to the last line, 
            // all lines in buffer shift one line up
            if (getLineCount() > BUFFERSIZE) {
                try {
                    replaceRange(null, getLineStartOffset(0), getLineEndOffset(0));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    append("An exception occured in replacing the topmost entry in the buffer");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
            append(text);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Swing Timer, not a TimerTask. The Swing Timer will execute on the EDT so you don't need the EventQueue.invokeLater().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have a buffer of 100 lines. Lets say the first line in the viewport is at line 40 when you turn scroll lock on.

If I understand your requirement you want line 40 to stay at the top of the viewport once you start removing lines from the Document. So as lines are deleted, the scrollbar will move to the top of the scroll pane. When line 40 is eventually deleted the scrollbar will be all the top of the scroll pane.

If so the following (rough) code my give you an idea:

```
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    //maybeScrollToBottom();
    int lineHeight = jTextArea.getPreferredSize().height / jTextArea.getLineCount();
    JViewport viewport = jScrollPane.getViewport();
    Point position = viewport.getViewPosition();
    position.y -= lineHeight;

    if (position.y > 0 )
        viewport.setViewPosition(position);
}
```

I doubt this code works exactly the way you want since once the buffer is full you can't just drag the scrollbar down to the bottom to have the viewport continually scroll as lines are appended. But it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Excellent solution @camickr.  It sure got me on the right path.  The only addition I had to make it working the way I wanted was to add a conditional to your code: `if(isScrollBarFullyExtended(jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar())) {
                maybeScrollToBottom();
            } else { //your code here}`